# grouping of data frame based on condition and return entire grouped data frame

Tags: r

Let's say I have following data frame. The first column is INPUT which have values such as 4000,4000,3000,2000,2000,2000,2000 etc. The second column is group which has value, such as- 1,1,2,3,3,3,3. 
Grouping has been done based on INPUT.
For example: INPUT IS:-

```
INPUT     group
4000       1
4000       1
2000       2
3000       3
2000       4
2000       4
2000       4
```

Output :- return entire data.frame which has maximum repeated group value.

```
INPUT     group
2000        4
2000        4
2000        4
```

I am having dataframe which have 10,0000 records, and 70 attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, get the nrow grouped by 'group' and subset the rows with `max` values in 'N'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, N:= .N, group][N==max(N)][, N:= NULL]
#    INPUT group
#1:  2000     4
#2:  2000     4
#3:  2000     4
```

Comment: this will return only one row i need all the records.

Comment: can you tell me how to iterate through all the groups, so the it will  return result like first group with maximum, then second data frame , then third and so on...

Comment: You can try `setDT(df1)[, N:=.N, group][order(group, -N)]` gets the dataset in the order

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `table` function and then find the max repeated value using `which.max`

```
df[df$group == which.max(table(df$group)), ]

#   INPUT group
#5  2000     4
#6  2000     4
#7  2000     4
```

As per @David's comment using `tabulate` instead of `table` here will be helpful as it is a large dataset

```
df[df$group == which.max(tabulate(df$group)), ]
```

Just did a small comparison on this dataset itself

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
tabulate = df[df$group == which.max(tabulate(df$group)), ],
table = df[df$group == which.max(table(df$group)), ]
)

# Unit: microseconds
# expr       min       lq      mean    median       uq     max   neval
# tabulate  46.871  51.1475  56.94295  53.714  62.4375  92.715    100
# table     184.747 192.4440 211.37036 203.905 216.3925 455.023   100
```

Comment: `tabulate` will be better in this case probably.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Not exactly sure how to use it. Just replacing `table` with `tabulate` gives the same result but I don't think this is how it is used.

Comment: `tabulate` is just the work horse of `table` so it will be faster for big data sets as you aren't using the names here anyway, rather just the position.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks David. Updated the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use base R. 
First calculate the counts for each group variable stratified by the INPUT variable

```
d$count <- ave(d$INPUT, d$group,  FUN = length)
```

Return the data which has maximum repeated group value.

```
d[ d$count == max(d$count),  ]
```